# GIMP - Can't get to fill a curved text

Tags: gimp, text, path, text-on-path

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-curve-text-in-gimp) to get a curved text. I am stucked in the final step when I want to fill the curved text red selection, like this :

[image: Red Selection]

I can't get to fill this curved red selection : I tried with Bucket Fill tool but the cursor indicates this is forbidden.

I tried also with "Stroke Path" but it doesn't do anything.

If you could help me, this would be nice...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The red line is not a selection but a path. You have to convert it to a selection before you can bucket-fill it: `Select>From path` (this should set the "marching ants" on it). If you have several paths `Select>From path` will pick the currently active path which may not be the right one, so open the Paths list (`Windows>Dockable dialogs>Paths`), identify the required path, right-click on it and click `Path to selection`

Comment: Thanks. I think that issue comes from the first text box I am writting (horizontal white message on figure above : "Curved message". I can't directly set this message along the curved line. Moreover, I can't get a text layer when I go on Windows->Dckable dialogs->Paths, is it normal ?

Comment: The tutorial you are following is not supposed to result in filled text, btw - it merely strokes the outlines of the text. And yes, layers do not appear in the paths dialog.

Comment: In the *Paths* dialog you deal with *Paths*, not with *Layers*. What happens under the covers is that the text in your original text layer is converted to a path, and then this path is bent to follow the curved path you created.

Comment: do I have to type firstly the text and then create the curved path or the contrary ? and how to fill the selected region in red ? If anyone has a tutorial to curve and fill text, could you send me please ? thanks

Comment: Text and "guide" path can be created in any order. To fill the "selection in red" see my answer.